# WPBakery Visual Composer keeps loading forever

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer, slick.js

I'm trying to edit a page with Visual Composer, But the page keeps loading, The preloader keeps loading the plugin logo.

Here is a screenshot of the issue:
[image: issue screenshot]

- WordPress version: 4.9.8
- Plugin version: 5.1.1

The console errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slick is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.eval (eval at <anonymous> (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget&ver=4.9.8:2), <anonymous>:3:65)
    at i (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget&ver=4.9.8:2)
    at Object.add [as done] (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget&ver=4.9.8:2)
    at a.fn.init.n.fn.ready (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget&ver=4.9.8:2)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget&ver=4.9.8:2), <anonymous>:2:18)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget&ver=4.9.8:2
    at Function.globalEval (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget&ver=4.9.8:2)
    at Ha (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget&ver=4.9.8:3)
    at a.fn.init.append (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,moxiejs,plupload,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget&ver=4.9.8:3)

14 Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image '<URL>'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to look at the last line. You need to load everything using HTTPS